# sync client database data to master database - laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm building a multi-tenant saas application using laravel 5.7 and vuejs. Whatever new client register the system will create new database for him as well all table migrations and seeding will be done via events. 
But when super admin manage the application, how to load each client data to super admin panel, or let's say super admin want to make a announcement to al of his client, how to handle this in laravel so announcement data get synced to all database.

Comment: What type of announcement are you referring to? If are just like messages, you could use [Laravel Event Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting) to emit messages and your clients will need to listen to this events.

Comment: I want to inform all of my clients about any specific thing which will happen in coming days like 'New downtime for maintenance etc' so from laravel i will create a notification and notify all of my clients but how do i access the data inside the super admin because each client will have their own database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe create a separate DB for `SUPER-ADMIN`, and that DB will be contains `clients_table` and other data needed to read/write data in clients-DB (data like client db name, user, password, for establish connection to his db etc.).

Alternatively - you can create special table `clients_announcments' in super-admin-db (or may be new db: common_clients_db) and use it for that (and read it from clients) - depends of how many clients you have and what efficency you need

If you create so "big" saas system with many DB, I also encourage you to hard separation between backend and frontend - this means laravel backend will only provide Restful API (NO html-css-js code - only pure php), and frotend client will be separate vue/angular/react project which will consume that API. Key words "micro-service architecture", "restful api"

Comment: When client register, new database will be created for him so all of his company data will live inside that database. There will be a master database where the plans, support queries of clients, faqs will be stored, but my question is how do i access the data stored in those databases when I logged in as superadmin, like what if super admin wants to update the plan expiry date to a specific client.

Comment: the super-admin will establish connection to clients db - look for keyword "multi db laravel connections": e.g. https://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: @JakyyB or may be this link will be better example - keyword "multi db dynamic laravel connections": https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/set-up-dynamic-database-connection-globally

Comment: I know about this and laravel support multi db connections, so if I have 50 clients then I have to manually connect to all 50 databases one by one and save announcement info inside those db table.

Comment: @JakyyB you can do it it that way, or you can create special table `clients_announcments' in super-admin-db (or may be new db: common_clients_db) and use it for that (and read it from clients) - depends of how many clients you have and what efficency you need

Comment: Thanks having one specific common database for announcements is good idea, I can then connect to this db inside client panel and show them the message. :)